# Angular 5 input within *ngFor not properly filling content

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 in this project, and there's a string array size 5 in this object property I want to show input field within a ngFor.

However, when I start typing any info on the first input text, it breaks my text and jumps to the next field, so it means I can't complete the text I was writing.

Here's an image to show whats happening.

[image]

When there's data in db, it properly shows it in the index it was registered, like: this is the document on my noSql database:

[image]

And this is the form retrieving data:

[image]

And, since it's properly showing the information, I thought the ngModel property was correctly defined... I dont have a clue why when I start typing any new text it is jumping to next input.

This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let email of user.email; let i = index">
    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-name">Field {{i}}</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="user.email[i]" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a trackBy in your ngFor. So, since you change the element of the array every time you enter something in it, Angular sees a new string in the array, destroys the div containing the input and recreates it. Since the input doesn't exist for a short while, the focis goes to the next one.

Solution: a trackBy:

```
trackByFn(index) {
  return index;
}

*ngFor="let email of user.email; trackBy: trackByFn; let i = index"
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nw1uhp-vcce1s?file=src/app/app.component.html

Other solution: storing objects rather than string in your array, and binding the email to a property of the object.